# ASP.net MVC Listbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a number of Html.Listbox controls on my view which are being populated by an `IEnumberable<SelectListItem>`

Is there a way that when the data is populated, that some items are automatically selected?

The particular selectlist items in the IEnumerable are marked as Selected = true, yet this does not convey into the view.

The view is as such:

```
<%= Html.ListBox("projects", Model.Projects)%>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Sure as always you start by defining a view model that will represent the information you would like to show on the particular view:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            SelectedItems = new[] { "1", "3" },
            Items = new[] 
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(
    x => x.SelectedItems, 
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text")
) %>
```

As expected *Item 1* and *Item 3* will be preselected when the list box is rendered.

Comment: Excellent that works as expected.  When I query this approach with my boss, and indeed what I had done before, he says that the MVC model should be stateless and that we should not keep track of data such as this.  Instead it should just pass data between View and Model and deal with what is passed only. Is that correct?  Thanks.